# Saving child only if it does not exists in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a parent class, say Parent. Its one of the property is another class, say Child. I want to save them such that

```
Parent {
   int id;
   Child child;
}

Child {
  int id;
}
```

1. If parent and child both does not exists in DB (mysql) then they should be inserted.
2. If the child already exists then it should not be inserted into DB.

In both the cases, the parent should hold the id of child in DB.

I want to do this in hibernate with Spring Boot. I am a novice in this stack.

Comment: what do you mean by 2. If the child already exists? the child c1 of parent p1 should be linked by a relationship. but you want to insert if other child c2 already exists - is this right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate for querying with the database and rest of the requirement can be implemented by writing below logic.

**1)** You need to create a function in DAO layer that will check whether both the parent p1 and child c1 does not exists in DB using select statement(Hibernate native/HQL).
If they do not exists then you can insert the data (p1 c1) in DB using hibernate.

**2)** Create a function in DAO layer to check whether the child record c1 already exists.
A select query can work with this. If it does not exists then you have to insert the record (p1 c1).

Comment: My question was more about using hibernate relationships. If we could use hibernate relationship to accomplish my motive.